# Install a ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am taking down a light fixture that has 2 wires, a black wire hot and a white wire neutral.  The ceiling fan I am installing has a Black wire a white wire and ground wire.  Do I just take the neutral wire and ground and put them together?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: One further note, most ceiling fans come with a cable to screw to stud so if the fan comes unmounted the cable catches the fan and also to help during install.  Don't skip attaching the cable, and actually screw it to a stud with an adequate sized washer.  Don't just attach it to the JB.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the white wire is your neutral, not ground. If you only have a white and a black out of the ceiling box, then I'm guessing the box is metal and probably grounded. Check the box to make sure it's rated for a ceiling fan. It usually says so inside. Install the fan bracket and then the fan. Hook the black hot to the black from the the fan. Hook the white neutral from the box to the white from the fan. Hook the bare copper or green wire from the fan to the box or green screw on the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

NO!  If something happens (ie: loose connection to the neutral between the fixture box and main panel), the entire fan assembly will become hot (energized), If you don't have a ground available, you're better off just leaving the ground wire disconnected.  Like JACK said, if the box is metal, and you are in an area that requires metal conduit, it might be grounded and connecting the bare wire to the box is all you need to do.   Also, please post a pic of the inside of the fixture box....if metal, there may be a ground wire attached to it that you missed.

Again, DO NOT connect the neutral and ground.